# Python error in virtuaenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, raspberry-pi

I have a script, which should run once per day by crontab. That works fine on my desktop. But when I try to run it on a virtualenv on my RPi, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailalert.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

It looks like I cant use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you install Django inside the `virtualenv`? It looks like you didn't. Go inside your `virtualenv` and run `pip --freeze` to check

Comment: How does the crontab entry look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

You need to configure the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in your `mailalert.py` script, prior to importing Django code.

Here's how you could do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "benchmarks.settings")

# Do you thing now.
```

## Virtualenv

Note that you code is probably not running inside a virtualenv right now, as made evidenced by the package paths (`/usr/local/lib` isn't your virtualenv):

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py"
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i change this path or run my script in the virtualenv?

Comment: Ok,.. i went into to my virtualenv by bin/acitvate and run the script. But there is still a problem:    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.